# How it works ^ Like with int type T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Column KategoriID int type (CategoryID)

```
select Name,KategoriID from Urunler
where KategoriID  Like '[^2]'
```

I expect removes just KategoriID = 2

when i write this query it removes all KategoriID contains 2
For Example 2 , 22,42,52 ID is removed.

why it is working like '[^2]%' ?

Comment: Why are you using string regualar expression comparisons on an `int` column?  Can you post some sample inputs and expected outputs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the SQL Server [LIKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) documentation:

> [^] Any single character not within the specified range ([^a-f]) or set ([^abcdef]).

So `[^2]` means where the value is NOT 2.

Also as this has no other components, it will only match on single character values that are not 2.

You could read it as saying, `any single character that is not 2` which excludes numbers greater than 9.

Comment: but it removes KategoriID 42,22,32 ext.

Comment: It will also remove 10, 100, 1000 etc. Does my edit clarify it for you?